# how to dynamically allocate character space to a structure field

Tags: c++, function, char, structure, allocation

Hi guys I need help to write this code: I've got error of segmentation writing the the name.

```
typedef struct employee{
  char *name;
  float salary;
  int stage;
}

employee;
void saisie(employee* listeEmployee,int  nb_employee){
  listeEmployee->name=new char(50);
  for(int i=0;i<nb_employee;i++){
    cout<<"Enter the name of employee, his salary and the stage" <<i<<endl;
    cin>>listeEmployee[i].name;
    cin>>listeEmployee[i].salary;
    cin>>listeEmployee[i].stage;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `std::string`?

Comment: of course I've included the package of string !

Comment: If you are permitted to use `std::string` then never do `new char(50);` or `char *name;` use `std::string name;` instead and the code will be much simpler and less error prone.

Comment: `listeEmployee->name=new char(50);` is your bug.

Comment: Don't use `typedef struct employee {...} employee;` in C++. This is necessary in C, but it is completely redundant in C++. Just use `struct employee { ... };` instead.

Comment: the program aborted after entering the first data and I got error of segmentation I mean the dynamic allocation of the name like char in the structure failed

Comment: @kouzin We know that. I told you the line that had a bug. I also told you that its best to not use `char* name;` at all.

Comment: I understand but the allocation can't success !

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use `char*` to save strings. Use `std::string` instead (requires `#include<string>`):

```
struct employee{
    std::string name;
    float salary;
    int stage;
};
```

and now you won't have to dynamically allocate anything. You can input into `name` with `cin >>` directly.

---

Your original `new` does not allocate memory for `50` characters, it allocates memory for *one* character and initializes it with the value `50`. You meant to use `[50]` instead of `(50)`.

Even then, you seem to be assuming that `listeEmployee` is an array, but you are allocating memory only for the first element in the array, while you try to input for multiple ones. You would need to `new` once for each `name` member of each array element, e.g. inside the loop body.

---

Don't use pointers for `listeEmployee` either. Wherever you are passing the array to the function, use `std::vector` instead of a raw array and then you can write (requires `#include<vector>`)

```
void saisie(std::vector<employee>& listeEmployee)
```

and you will be able to get the correct size of `listeEmployee` with `listeEmployee.size()` at any time without error in passing it along.

Comment: @kouzin Comments purely to thank someone else are not much liked here. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for things you can (but don't have to) do if someone answered your question.